# Ad Banner Implementation in Activities of Android Application

Tags: java, android, advertisement-server

I am building an Android App for a company that contains 'sponsors' (ads in form of banners).Does anyone help me with the sample code and procedure for implementing ads in my Apps' activities?

Comment: http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.add_view);      
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();               
adview.loadAd(re);
```

and xml

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.flash.light"
    android:id="@+id/add_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14e843bea82be1"/>
```

values folder attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
  <attr name="adSize">
      <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
      <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
      <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
      <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
  </attr>
  <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
```

add jar file to u r project.